# React material UI doesn't bind the initialValue to the AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a component called `form.js`. The component has two status, update state and creates state. There I have `AutoComplete` component. It's working fine with the create state. (Data creating is working fine)

But when I try to use the same component as update component. `customerId` is set correctly to the component state. But does not show the relavent customer name in the `AutoComplete` field.

[image]

```
const agents = [
  { name: "Pathum", id: 1 },
  { name: "Chamod", id: 2 },
  { name: "Avishka", id: 3 }
];

<FormControl style={{width:'100%'}}>
                          <Autocomplete
                            id="combo-box-demo"
                            options={agents}
                            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                            style={{ width: '100%' }}
                            onChange={(e, v) => {
                              if (v) {
                                setFieldValue("customerId", v.id);
                              } else {
                                setFieldValue("customerId", "");
                              }
                            }}
                            renderInput={(params) => {
                              return (
                                <TextF
                                  {...params}
                                  label="Combo box"
                                  variant="outlined"
                                />
                              );
                            }}
                          />
                        </FormControl>
```

I pass this agents array to the AutoComplete component. customerId 3 is selected. So Idealy I want to see the name Avishka in the AutoComplete component instead it is empty.

Hope my question is clear to all.
This is full code https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-z8kjq?file=/demo.js:1842-1949

Comment: You code example should also include your AutoComplete, which currently it does not. That's where the problem occurs, so if you want us to help, we need to see that part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `Autocomplete` is uncontrolled and is primarily utilized for your forms, just assign a `defaultValue`

```
<Autocomplete
  defaultValue={agents[2]}
/>
```

Alternatively, you could switch to a controlled component. Value will be based off of Formik `values`

```
<Autocomplete
  value={agents.find((agent) => agent.id === values.customerId)}
/>
```

Comment: Hi, this second option works fine in the code sandbox. But when I apply that to the real project it doesn't work. In real project agents array set from an API call. Is that the reason?

Comment: probably, the agents data is not readily available in that case so the `Autocomplete` has to re-render according to the new data fetched from the API (e.g., make `agents` into a state)